# how to avoid / block e-commerce bots?

Tags: php, e-commerce

I am working in a big ecommerce platform from a very well known shoes brand here in my country, and our website have a page dedicated to a exclusive product This product sell just a few units, so by this reason people try to buy it desperately.
most of these people resell our products, so they try to buy as many products as possible.
We try to control the quantity bought by every person we limit how much of each product they can buy. So other people can buy them too, but this is not enough, they're using bots now to buy those products, so they can buy before someone else tries it.
That makes our customers very angry about that.

Our ecommerce runs with PHP, and we tried block those bots adding recaptcha. But they still pass for any way in defiance of our captcha.

So my question is:

Is there any way to prevent bots from buying the products?
Any idea of what we can do to prevent them?
Any technique, implementation, any idea of what we can do?

We're getting out of ideas here, so I am open to any feedback about that.

We don't use any famous platform like magento, opencart, etc. It's our own custom platform.

Comment: Better captchas maybe?

Comment: captchas can always be defeated. (for example using humans to solve them) I think the only possible way is to make sure the users accounts are real and unique, for example by requiring a phone number and verifying it by sms, or verifying the passport. Not very nice/userfriendly though.

Comment: (How) do you know that these are really bots and not genuine customers?

Comment: Surely the best way is to just sell the products to the bots. That way you make more money.

Comment: @Pradyumna because of time/quantity items they bought at once, we also saw a lot of videos on youtube of people selling even chrome extensions that buy our products in a few seconds, like a task manager in the browser

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sell only limited amounts to individual customers, a standard e-commerce solution will not work because it is optimized for streamlined sales to many customers. You will need to add some KYC component and maybe manual vetting to protect against bots. You can't entirely protect against resellers using middlemen to buy from you, but you can probably drive up their overhead and make it unprofitable for them.

In any case, this is a situation where you need an effective policy first, only afterwards you can build the technical processes to implement/enforce the policy. As you don't seem to have the policy yet, asking for a technical solution here is likely premature.

Comment: Sending an OTP to their mobile number (a local mobile number) could be a simple KYC step that defeats most bots

Comment: That could help a bit, yes. I was thinking of live video chat with product recommendations by a human, which would also confer some exclusivity. After all, it's exclusivity that you're selling here, not shoes primarily :-)